# How to start the echo service on OSX Mountain Lion to respond to autossh monitoring

Tags: macos, ssh, monitoring, osx-mountain-lion, autossh

I have the following two machines :

Machine A. OSX Machine which will act as the SSH server
Machine B. An SSH client connecting to the above using [autossh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh)

autossh allows persistent, self-healing connections to be made and restarts the child ssh process if it exited abnormally (the man page has details about what 'abnormal' means). Specifically, I am interested in allowing scenario #4 to work:

> Periodically (by default every 10 minutes), autossh attempts to pass
>   traffic on the monitor forwarded port. If this fails, autossh will
>   kill the child ssh process (if it is still running) and start a new
>   one

**Questions**:

1. What is the recommended monitoring approach with autossh? Would it be monitoring on specific ports or using the echo service ? Or would it be to rely on OpenSSH's ServerAliveDelay so that ssh connections exit timely and disable autossh monitoring altogether?
2. If it's the latter, how do I start the echo service on osx? From the wiki page of [inetd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) :

> As of version Mac OS X v10.4, Apple has merged the functionality of
>   inetd into launchd.

Therefore, how do I use launchd to start the echo service on osx Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you stick with `ServerAliveDelay` and `ServerAliveInterval`, both of which can be specified inside a local `ssh_config` file. This will obviate the need for either a monitoring port or the use of the echo service, and will allow the ssh client to handle graceful exits while enabling autossh to restart lost connections.